# How can I annotate my genes in R using the select(org.Mm.eg.db) function if the original information I have for each gene is their ENSEMBL ID?

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am trying to figure out how I can annotate my set of genes using the following approach so that I can perform a pathway analysis of my annotated differentially expressed genes

This is the line of code I am having trouble with:

```
ann <- select(org.Mm.eg.db,keys=rownames(fit.cont),columns=c("ENTREZID","SYMBOL","GENENAME"))
```

I am trying to generate entrez IDs, symbols, and gene names for each of the genes in my final object.

Basically - I started with an original matrix 'readcounts_g', which has 10 samples of RNA-seq read counts data for 20k genes and rownames corresponding to ENSEMBL IDs.

Next, i executed the following lines of code:

```
z <- DGEList(readcounts_g)
z <- calcNormFactors(z)
v2 <- voom(z,design.mat,plot = TRUE)
fit2 <- lmFit(v2)
```

## Generating a design matrix that specifies that first 5 samples are KO and second 5 are WT for our experimental condition.

```
design.mat <- cbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0), c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))
colnames(design.mat) <- c("KO_GCC", "WT_GCC")
design.mat

cont.matrix2 <- makeContrasts(A.WTvsKO2=KO_GCC - WT_GCC,levels = design.mat)
fit.cont2 <- contrasts.fit(fit2, cont.matrix)
fit.cont2 <- eBayes(fit.cont2)
summa.fit2 <- decideTests(fit.cont2)
ann <- select(org.Mm.eg.db,keys=rownames(fit.cont),columns=c("ENTREZID","SYMBOL","GENENAME"))
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to use:

```
topTable(fit.cont2,coef="A.WTvsKO",sort.by="p")
```

1. I want this so that I can spit out a table of the top differentially expressed genes along with their gene names etc.
2. I also want to be able to plot volcano plots and other graphics with the gene names rather than the ID numbers that I currently have

Another concern was whether or not when I execute the `goana` function, if it will be able to properly recognize which genes are in my dataset despite only have the ENSEMBL ID numbers instead of the ENTREZ ID numbers

```
go <- goana(fit.cont2, coef="A.WTvsKO",species = "Mm")
```

Here is an example of the set that I am working with:

```
library(dplyr)

data_g = tibble(geneID=sample(1:3),
              s1=rpois(3,10),s2=rpois(3,15),
                s3=rpois(3,20),s4=rpois(3,25))

data_g$gene_name = c("ENSMUSG00000042638","ENSMUSG00000030214","ENSMUSG00000030222")
rownames(data_g) = data_g$gene_name

data = data_g[,-1]
data_1 = data[,-5]
rownames(data_1) = data$gene_name
data_1 = as.matrix(data_1)
```

From here, data_1 is essentially a truncated version of the matrix that I am working with for my real data.

I am trying to annotate this matrix with Entrez gene IDs so i can use the goana function in limma.

I thought this below line would work, where i specify the 'key types' as ensemble ID #s and it returns entrez IDs:

ann <- select(org.Mm.eg.db,keys = rownames(fit.cont2),keytypes="ENSEMBL", columns=c("ENTREZID"))

Comment: Please provide some sample data, in order to create an reproducible example

Comment: hey bruno - i wrote some code that creates a similar matrix to the one I am dealing with. I am really just trying to generate annotations from org.Mm.eg.db using the ENSEMBL gene id's that I currently have as row names. I need them in the entrez format for the goana function enrichment analysis. thank you!!

Comment: You need to break this question into smaller pieces, I am not a biologist but I doubt they will solve this as it stands